# Composing functions with more than one variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In class we learned that to compose two functions say $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = x+1$ we plug one function into another. So $f(g(x)) = 2x + 2$. But what happens when we have more than one variable? Say I have $h(x,y) = \frac{2x}{1-y}$ is it possible to do $f(h(x,y))$ and if so how?

Comment: Yes, possible. And: just like you wrote: taking e.g. $f(\,h(x,y)\,)$ where $f$ is *unary*.

Comment: So I just plug $h(x,y)$ into x, the only variable available in $f$?

Comment: How did you get $2x - 2$? It should be $2x+2$.

Comment: Yes thank you, it's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

We have $$f\left( h(x,y)\right) = \frac{4x}{1 - y}$$How: take a pair $(x,y)$, $y \neq 1$and evaluate $h(x,y)$ to get a value. Then you plug this value, say $z := h(x,y)$, into $f$. This would be the value $f(z)$.